# Replace lockscreen background image using adb

Tags: adb, lock-screens, background-process

I am using a Lenovo Vibe Shot phone, which has Android 6.0.1 on it. In one of the updates, the change lockscreen background feature stopped work, so I can't change the background, now, regardless of where I try to do it from: settings, gallery, Google Play or 3rd party apps that are made to do that or try to implement the functionality(trust me, if there was a normal way to do it, I'd have found it).

So I've figured out I could maybe use adb to replace my lockscreen background.

Basically, what I'm asking is if there are any special commands in adb shell to do this? If not, does anybody know the location, where Android 6.0.1 stores its lockscreen image? Or if that's not the case, does anybody know the file, which has the string/line that points to the location of the lockscreen background file?

Any of the above mentioned methods are good enough for me. As far as I can see, adb is basically a limited bash shell, or at least has a mode similar to that. So if I get the file location, command or string location, I'll probably be able to continue by myself.

Comment: Have you checked here:  `/system/wallpaper`

Answer (score 0):

I do not own a Lenovo device, but many individuals claim lockscreen images are stored here: `/storage/emulated/0/.lelauncher/wallpaper`.

You may want to check this Lenovo support forum: [Custom picture for lockscreen](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Android-Yoga-Series-Tablets/Custom-picture-for-lockscreen/td-p/1794099)